# How to split CamelCase into a list (python)

Tags: list, python-3.x, camelcasing

I have been trying for a month and can't get anywhere with this. I have an exam very soon but I can't figure this out. I need a way to split a CamelCase statement into a list in python, and the list should have room for 10 words. If less than 10 words are in the statement then the empty spots on the list should say (Empty).

[edit]
the input would be something like ThisIsCamelCase
and the expected output would be an array the contents of which are
This
Is
Camel
Case
(Empty)
(Empty)

so far I've been able to put this together:

`def un_camel(input):
     output = [input[0].lower()]
     for c in input[1:]:
             if c in ('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'):
                     output.append(' ')
                     output.append(c.lower())
             else:
                     output.append(c)
     return str.join('', output)`
It can split camel case but not accomplish the array part

Comment: Generally people get frustrated when they don't get solution even for 1 day, so they ask for help! ^_^ How could you try for month? Anyway can you post input and their expected output plzz ;)

Comment: It might help to show us some code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: @PriyeshKumar yeah i just edited the question

Comment: @KarolineBrynildsen check the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a regular expression would do most of the job:

```
In [10]: import re

In [11]: re.sub('([a-z])([A-Z])', r'\1 \2', 'ThisIsCamelCase').split()
Out[11]: ['This', 'Is', 'Camel', 'Case']
```

Make the list 10 items long:

```
In [23]: a = re.sub('([a-z])([A-Z])', r'\1 \2', 'ThisIsCamelCase').split()

In [24]: a + [None]*(10 - len(a))
Out[24]: ['This', 'Is', 'Camel', 'Case', None,
           None, None, None, None, None]
```

(This seems like an unPythonic thing to do, by the way).

If you *must* use `(Empty)` instead of a sensible value like `None`:

```
In [26]: a + ['(Empty)']*(10 - len(a))
Out[26]: 
['This', 'Is', 'Camel', 'Case', '(Empty)',
 '(Empty)', '(Empty)', '(Empty)', '(Empty)', '(Empty)']
```

Comment: dude you're a lifesaver. As far as the (Empty) thing goes that was basically specified to us by the exam board and we don't really have a say in that matter.